# how to change wordpress title using mysql command

Tags: wordpress

how to change website title using mysql query?
my website CMS is a Wordpress and my dbms is a mysql and my os is ubuntu.

I want run a single `mysql command` in ubuntu for change the `wordpress` title.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At first, you need to check your website database table prefix & change it into SQL Query. Default WordPress table prefix 'wp'. You can update the WordPress site title via a simple SQL query.
SQL Query:

```
UPDATE `wp_options` SET `option_value` = 'Your new site title' WHERE `wp_options`.`option_id` = 3;
```